# parsing Json with weird attribute names

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse the following objects into C# objects. The json element looks like this:

```
{
"type": "node",
"id": 101440589,
"lat": 52.0952096,
"lon": 5.1266853,
"tags": {
    "addr:city": "Utrecht",
    "addr:housenumber": "44",
    "addr:postcode": "3572CA",
    "addr:street": "Wittevrouwensingel",
    "amenity": "restaurant",
    "contact:website": "http://spaghetteria-pastabar.nl/",
    "cuisine": "italian",
    "name": "Spaghetteria",
    "old_name": "Kimono",
    "source": "BAG",
    "source:date": "2014-02-11"
  }
},
```

The issues is getting the values from the tags list. C# doesn't like the : in the name. How would I go around doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use the JsonProperty Attribute. there you can define how the field is named when serialized

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know this was already answered